# How do I retrieve three levels of nested data and keep it type safe using interfaces in Angular 2 and AngularFire2

Tags: angular, typescript, angularfire2

I try to retrieve nested data from firebase and keep it type safe. I have had a look at this:
https://github.com/aaronksaunders/afwithngcli/blob/master/src/app/afwithngcli.component.ts
but it does not use interfaces.

My interfaces (simplified for this sample):

```
export interface IStudy {
  $key?: string;
  description: string;
  subjects: ISubject[];
}

export interface ISubject {
  $key?: string;
  description: string;
  someOtherData: string;
  classes: IClass[];
}

export interface IClass {
  $key?: string;
  description: string;
  someOtherData: string;
}
```

My service:

```
@Injectable()
export class MyService {
  private myStudies$: FirebaseListObservable<IStudy[]>;

  constructor(af: AngularFire, auth: AuthService) {
    this.myStudies$ = af.database.list(`/studies/${auth.id}`).map((studies: IStudy[]) => {
      return studies.map(study => {
        study.subjects = af.database.list(`/subjects/${study.$key}`).map((subjects: Subject[]) => {
          return subjects.map(subject => {
            subject.classes = af.database.list(`/classes/${subject.$key}`);
            return subject;
          })
        });
        return study;
      })
    })
  }

  getMyStudies(): Observable<IStudy[]> {
    return this.myStudies$;
  }
}
```

What I try to do is get all my studies including all subjects and classes, as observables, so that I can display and edit all levels in one component.

I get errors saying:

```
Type 'Observable<IStudy[]>' is not assignable to type 'FirebaseListObservable<IStudy[]>'.
Property '_ref' is missing in type 'Observable<IStudy[]>'.

Type 'Observable<ISubject[]>' is not assignable to type 'ISubject[]'.
Property 'length' is missing in type 'Observable<ISubject[]>'.

Type 'FirebaseListObservable<any[]>' is not assignable to type 'IClass[]'.
Property 'length' is missing in type 'FirebaseListObservable<any[]>'.
```

The problem is in the constructor, error highlighting that there are errors assigning to this.myStudies$, study.subjects and subject.classes.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

FirebaseListObservable is a different type than Observable. Try changing:

```
 getMyStudies(): Observable<IStudy[]> {
    return this.myStudies$;
  }
```

to

```
getMyStudies(): FirebaseListObservable <IStudy[]> {
    return this.myStudies$;
}
```

Edit: I think you should avoid such deep nesting calls for observables but at second glance you have a bug here:

You are assigning `FirebaseListObservable` to  `subject.classes`.

Comment: I edited the answer, see if it helps. Paste new errors if they appear

Comment: I get the same errors. You suggest that I do avoid deep nesting, but how do you suggest that I solve this? As you can see from the link in my question other people are doing nesting, so it is possible, only I can't get it to work.

Comment: Did you try checking what types do you return in the map functions ?